# How to change the name an encrypted full-system partition is mapped to

Tags: dm-crypt

My system is fully encrypted with `dm-crypt` and `LVM`. I recently moved the encrypted partition from `/dev/sda5` to `/dev/sda2`.

My question is: how can I change the name the encrypted partition is mapped to from `sda5_crypt` to `sda2_crypt`?

I can boot the system all right. But the prompt I get at boot time says `(sda5_crypt)` though the `UUID` maps to `/dev/sda2`:

```
  Volume group "vg" not found
  Skipping volume group vg
Unlocking the disk /dev/.../UUID  (sda5_crypt)
Enter passphrase:
```

I tried to live-boot, decrypt `sda2`, activate `vg`, `chroot` to `/dev/vg/root` and run `update-grub2` but to no avail.

Merely editing `/etc/crypttab` doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you recreated the initrd after editing `/etc/crypttab`?

Comment: I think so: `update-initramfs -t -u -k all`

Comment: Output of `grep -r sda5_crypt /etc`?

Comment: Found the issue: I must mount `/dev/sda1` as `/boot` **before** running `update-initramfs`.

Comment: Make that an answer instead of a comment and accept it (if that is possible with own answers, I am not sure) so that this question is shown as answered.

Comment: As a note, this is why it's common practice to name volumes after what is on the volume, not what the volume is on. I can't know your exact scenario, but I would recommend the practice.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"sda5_crypt" crypttab change as per suggestion below:

Replace `OLD_NAME` with `NEW_NAME` in `/etc/crypttab` & `/etc/fstab`, and then:

```
# dmsetup rename OLD_NAME NEW_NAME
# cp -a /dev/mapper/NEW_NAME /dev/mapper/OLD_NAME
# update-initramfs -u -k all
# rm /dev/mapper/OLD_NAME
# update-grub
# reboot
```

Comment: rescue should not be necessary. just edit the crypttab, update-initramfs, and next time you boot it should be renamed. You can also rename it in the running system using `dmsetup rename oldname newname`. Note that this does not free the old name, as it may be in use.

Comment: @frostschutz You have to be able to get at that `/etc/crypttab` file somehow… Doing the mounting manually from the initramfs shell so that you can boot the normal system is possible, but not easy. A rescue system is the quicker option if you aren't intimately familiar with `cryptsetup` and LVM commands.

Comment: @Gilles: sure, but the question stated "I can boot the system all right."

Comment: You just saved me a big headache @n.r. Thank you

Comment: This is the right method, but a few more details should be pointed out: 1) Don't forget to update `/etc/fstab` before these commands, too, or you're root partition won't mount. 2) You may receive an error on `update-grub` that it can't find the previous name. Assuming you're only renaming the crypt name, then you can ignore the error, reboot, and run `update-grub` after you boot up.

Comment: There's no `update-initramfs` or `update-grub` in recent Fedora installations, here `dracut --force` appears to do the trick in generating the `initrd`. The Grub configuration doesn't need to be changed as it's referring to the root device via its (unchanged) UUID anyway.

Comment: @Fmstrat Yes, updating /etc/fstab is essential, but for configurations with LVM this turns out to be completely "self-healing": with LVM you'll have only LVM mappings in /etc/fstab...

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue - with the additional complication that I haven't seen the warning of the last `update-initramfs`. So I renamed the device in `crypttab`, ran `update-initramfs`, restarted and had a problem. I solved it as follows, basically the same n.r. but I had to alter the commands slightly:

1. Boot a Live (K)Ubuntu System from USB
2. Open the device in Dolphin/? which setups all the needed configuration and asks you your password
3. Open the console in the root directory of your broken system
4. Execute the following line by line

```
sudo -s
# get the name the partition was mounted with, starts with luks
dmsetup ls
# rename the loop device (check with ls /dev/mapper)
dmsetup rename LUKS_NAME NEW_NAME

# prepare chroot
mount --bind /dev dev/
mount --bind /proc proc/
mount --bind /sys sys/
chroot .

# mount devices (I missed this first, you need both)
mount boot
mount /

# ready to update
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Comment: Every Debian GNU/Linux installation media (ISOs for CD, DVD, USB pen drive) has a rescue boot option which does a lot of this for you, specifically it will mount your root directory, asking for the password, and provide a rescure shell via chroot into it. From there you have access to /etc/fstab, making the following steps a lot easier: `mount /boot` and then `update-initramfs -u -k all` and all is set. Add `update-grub` if you want. `exit` and reboot.